# How to select an excel data Table using a drop downlist value

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I am working on an application that uses excel files as its data source. I would love the `DataGridView` to populate with the columns of a sheet when a worksheet name is selected from the drop down list.

Here is what I have tried doing:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form101
    Public cn As New OleDbConnection
    Public cm As New OleDbCommand
    Public da As OleDbDataAdapter

    Dim comb As String

    Public dt As New DataTable
    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Comb1.SelectedIndexChanged
        comb = Comb1.SelectedText
    End Sub
    Public Sub FillDataGridView(ByVal Query As String)
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(Query, cn)
        dt.Clear()
        da.Fill(dt)

        With DataGridView1
            .DataSource = dt
            .Columns(0).HeaderText = "Date"
            .Columns(1).HeaderText = "Qty brought"
            .Columns(2).HeaderText = "Qty sold"
            .Columns(3).HeaderText = "Goods balance"
            .Columns(1).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        cn.ConnectionString = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\toojah app\Stock card.xls; Extended Properties= Excel 8.0;"
        cn.Open()

        FillDataGridView("select * FROM ['" & comb & "'] ")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. The first function will collect all of the columns and records in your excel file and place it into a datatable. Then If you wanted to add additional columns to the datable you can do it in the Public Sub CreateDataGridView. This has been tested and works.

```
Friend Shared Function BuildDatatable () as datatable

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim Conn As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim cmd As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter



        dim MyFile as string = "C:\toojah app\Stock card.xls"


                    Conn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + MyFile + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';")
                    Conn.Open()
                    Dim dtSheets As DataTable = Conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
                    Dim listSheet As New List(Of String)
                    Dim drSheet As DataRow
                    For Each drSheet In dtSheets.Rows
                        listSheet.Add(drSheet("TABLE_NAME").ToString())
                        cmd = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" & drSheet("TABLE_NAME").ToString() & "]", Conn)
                        cmd.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net-informations.com")
                        cmd.Fill(dt)
                        Conn.Close()
                    Next

        Return dt

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try

End Function

'This is used to pass the function datatable as a dt to then pass to the public sub as shown below. 
Dim dt As DataTable = BuildDatatable


Public Sub CreateDataGridView(dt)

Dim newColumn As New Data.DataColumn("ComeColumnName", GetType(System.String))     
newColumn.DefaultValue = "YourValues"
dt.Columns.Add(newColumn)

DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

End Sub
```

Comment: I Added the HDR=YES extended property and its still giving error in connection

Comment: what is the error and where are you getting it? I thought that you just wanted to show the excel columns in your datagrid view?

Comment: I still get OleDb Exception was unhandled in the Public Sub FillDataGridView(ByVal Query As String). da.Fill(dt)

Comment: I added additional code that I have used in the past to collect data from excel that builds a datagridview.

Comment: No errors, but where does the drop down list box comes into action, on button click

Comment: Well, you can have Comb1.SelectedIndexChanged routine select the excel sheet which then does the rest of the stuff or you could have everything in that routine or call the other Routines That did not give you an error. Your choice.